# Laravel - Mensaje de validación en archivo

Tags: laravel

```
<input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="control" name="archivo">
        @if ($errors->has('archivo'))
            <span class="help-block text-danger">
             <strong>{{ $errors->first('archivo') }}</strong>
           </span>
       @endif



$this->validate($request, [
        'archivo.*' => 'required | mimes:jpeg,jpg,png',
]);
```

Pero no me sale el mensaje de error al momento de validar, debido a que es un array de inputs files, como seria la validación para esto y que me muestre el mensaje?.

Comment: trata de poner algo mas de codigo del controlador y de la vista para poder ayudarte

Comment: En teoría la validación es correcta así, aunque yo no pondría los espacios entre las reglas y el pipe que separa. ¿Funciona si es un solo archivo?

Answer (score 1):

debes hacerlo asi:

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'archivo' => 'required',
        'archivo.*' => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png',
]);
```

**view:**

```
<input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="control" name="archivo">
    @if ($errors->any())
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <span class="help-block text-danger">
             <strong>{{ $error }}</strong>
           </span>
        @endforeach
    @endif
```

**referencia:** 
[validate laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation)

Comment: Pero no necesito todos, necesito especialmente los de archivo. Como puedo hacer el recorrido con el `foreach` de solo 'archivo'